# Outlook VSTO - mailItem body problems

Tags: c#, email, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin

I'm having a problem with email sending in C#.

I'm working on an add-in and everything is going well. I can send my mails, like i want, but not "two times in a row".
For example, my add-in open a Form and after the user action an email is sent.
When the mail is sent, the form is closed and that's okay.

But some time, i need to send two separate emails and the body of second email is always empty. By the way, i fill the "body" of my mails with Word (**Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word**) to have some formatted text.
If I use the **.Body** property there is no problem.

Now, I'm wondering if it's not the fault of "Word" because the email part is working but only the body is empty.
I tried to send my mails in the inverse order to see if it's occurs always with the second mail and i was right. It's not about the email or his content but more about being the second sent.
It may be some things which haven't been released yet(not properly released objects) or something like that but i'm doing already it.

That's how i'm doing..

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)new Outlook.Application().CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
try
{
    mailItem.CC = currentUserExchange.PrimarySmtpAddress;
    mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
    mailItem.Subject = "XXX";
    mailItem.To = finalRecipients;
    fillBody(mailItem, mailBody);
    mailItem.Send();
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
finally
{
    releaseObject(mailItem);
}


if (moderatorPin != String.Empty)
{
    Outlook.MailItem mailItemSecurity = (Outlook.MailItem)new Outlook.Application().CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
    try
    {
        mailItemSecurity.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
        mailItemSecurity.Subject = "XXX";
        mailItemSecurity.To = currentUserExchange.PrimarySmtpAddress;
        fillBody(mailItemSecurity, mailBodySecure);
        mailItemSecurity.Send();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("error : " + ex.Message); }
    finally
    {
        releaseObject(mailItemSecurity);
    }

}
```

and :

```
private void fillBody(Outlook.MailItem mailItem, String bodyMail)
{
    Word.Document document = mailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
    Word.Range rng = document.Paragraphs[1].Range;
    try
    {
        document.Paragraphs[1].LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpaceSingle;

        rng.set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHtmlKbd);
        rng.Font.Color = (Word.WdColor)(fontColor.R + 0x100 * fontColor.G + 0x10000 * fontColor.B);
        rng.Text = bodyMail;
        rng.Select();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("XXX");
    }
    finally
    {
        releaseObject(rng);
        releaseObject(document);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use MailItem.HTMLBody instead?

Comment: Yeah, that's what i ended up to do. Thanks for the answer. 
I didn't want to use it first because also I need to fill the body of an AppointmentItem and there is no HTMLBody property in it.
Finally I did use an html content with both object (MailItem and AppointmentItem). It was easy for the MailItem but with the AppointmentItem I used a webBrowser to form an html page then i copied it and pasted it on the body (with the WordEditor of the Inspector). I don't really like that but I didn't have another solution and it works.
By the way, you did a great job with OutlookSpy, it's a good tool :)